# Problems with clean Windows 8 install

Tags: windows-8

I've downloaded Windows 8 from Microsoft in our Microsoft Action Pack Subscription. Perhaps I need to ask them, but I think I'll get better help here.

I recently bought a new computer at work and inserted a new SSD drive. I installed Windows 8 Professional but I got "Windows 8". To get Professional I needed to to an edition upgrade - which also was the first time I had to enter the serial.

Everything first seemed ok. But now I've noticed some strange stuff. I have a laptop with Windows 8 to compare differences with.

- I can't change power options, when I try to I get a message saying they can't be changed - "Enheten är inte klar" it says in Swedish - "Device not ready" perhaps in English.
- In the "PC Settings" menu "Users" and "Windows Update" is missing.
- All services (service.msc) are listed with short names, "BITS" instead of "Background Intelligent Transfer". Most of them has an error code 2 as description.
- I can't add some of the features in "Turn Windows features on and off", like anything for .NET 3.5

I don't know if all or any of these things are related. It's just too many problems in a two days old clean install. My collegue used the same installation DVD also doing a clean install and got Professional edition at install, no edition upgrade needed. He doesn't have any of the problems I have. We are both network administrators and local administrators on our machines.

Comment: run this DISM command and hope it fixes the issue: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be because of AMD Catalyst Un-install Utility...

http://www.overclock.net/t/1350750/win-8-users-warning-about-amd-uninstallation-utility